# QGIS character spacing in label inserted in print layout

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-print-layouts

I normally insert labels directly through Layer Properties, which allows one to vary character spacing. However, I need to insert labels in Print Layout for a particular project and cannot find a way to manipulate character spacing in Print Layout. Can it be done?

[image: Screenshot showing label properties]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use HTML tags and CSS to style labels. Use HTML in text box and check `Render as HTML` checkbox.

```html
<p style="letter-spacing: 1">Test</p>
<p style="letter-spacing: 5">Test</p>
<p style="letter-spacing: 20">Test</p>
```

[image]

Comment: Great tip, thank you for that! I really wish they could incorporate some of these options into the text box font settings, like they do with labels. Right now it makes text layout in maps seem unnecessarily complicated (albeit super customisable... if you know HTML...)